# How to filter an ActiveAndroid Delete statement with a date field

Tags: android, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I try to delete from a table where there is a date field (represented as a string).
I'd like to do it by the following statement:

```
Object result=new Delete().from(Information.class).where("Date>=?", date.replace(".","-")).execute();
```

It seems that nothing was deleted, the result variable is null.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I get the number of the deleted objects?
2. How can I use a where with a date variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the object side, not the ActiveAndroid/SQLite side. SQLite can use dates for comparison but the *source date has to be LocalDateTime.* As you can see, I've been using Strings so the comparison gave false results.

Comment: That's not working for me. I'm using LocalDateTime and it gives false result anyways.

Comment: Did you use LocalDateTime or Date? Try both.

Answer (score 0):

Dont you have to add the (') char to a date?

```
Object result=new Delete().from(Information.class).where("Date>='?" + "'", date.replace(".","-") ).execute();
```

Like that?

Comment: No, the problem is not on the ActiveAndroid/SQLite side, it is the date. See my answer for details.